# Rails Javascript Link_tos

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, action, link-to

In my rails app i have these two `link_to` which both obviously do something. When i

```
<% if Excont.where(:user_id=> current_user,:movie_id => @movie.id,:actionall => '2').includes(:user).all.count == 0%>

<tr style="border-top: none; ">
    <td>
        <%= link_to('Mark as action', {:controller => :excont, :action => 'thisisanaction', :id=> @movie.id, :actionall=>'2'}, :method => :post, :remote => true,  :disable_with => 'Updating...') %>
    </td>
</tr>

<% else %>

<tr style="border-top: none;">
    <td>
        <%= link_to('Unmark as action', {:controller => :excont, :action => 'removethisisanaction', :id=> @movie.id, :actionall=>'2'}, :method => :post, :remote => true,  :disable_with => 'Updating...') %>
    </td>
</tr>

<% end %>
```

When I click on the first `link_to` (thisisanaction), it runs the `Updating...` and then goes back to `Mark as action`, if i reload it'll have changed to `Unmark as action`.

What I'm asking is how to go from

`Mark as action` -> `Updating...` -> `Unmark as action`

and then

`Unmark as action` --> `Updating...` -> `Mark as action`

without having to reload the page. How would my JS code look like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i fixed it

I put this into a separate file called _action.html.erb

```
<% if Excont.where(:user_id=> current_user,:movie_id => @movie.id,:actionall => '2').includes(:user).all.count == 0%>

<tr style="border-top: none; ">
    <td>
        <%= link_to('Mark as action', {:controller => :excont, :action => 'thisisanaction', :id=> @movie.id, :actionall=>'2'}, :method => :post, :remote => true,  :disable_with => 'Updating...') %>
    </td>
</tr>

<% else %>

<tr style="border-top: none;">
    <td>
        <%= link_to('Unmark as action', {:controller => :excont, :action => 'removethisisanaction', :id=> @movie.id, :actionall=>'2'}, :method => :post, :remote => true,  :disable_with => 'Updating...') %>
    </td>
</tr>

<% end %>
```

I then created two `.js.erb` files named after both of the action (which is very important i've found), so `thisisanaction.js.erb` and `removethisisanaction.js.erb`.

These two files have to be both placed in the folder of the appropriate controller, in this case `excont`, if not it wont work.

Both of these folders should contain this code

```
$(".excontaction").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('layouts/action'))%>");
```

In the view where you want the button to show you add this

```
<div class="excontaction">
<%= render 'layouts/action' %>
</div>
```

The div `class` or `id` should match the one you put in the `.js.erb` folders

This should work!